# Querying Current Data from Historical Data

Tags: postgresql, python-3.5, peewee

I've been working on this personal project for a while and I'm racking my brain over this one problem.

Every 20 minutes, my cron grabs data from posts in a subreddit. The data includes details like upvote count, upvote ratio, etc. I also have a column for the time that the data was collected so I can find the most current data for each submission.

The current data is displayed on a webpage for that submission, and the historical data for that submission is displayed as charts and graphs on that page, so I need both sets.

Some sample columns for table structure:

```
reddit_id | retrieval_time | total_upvotes | upvote_ratio | num_comments
```

The table contains multiple reddit_ids each with their own individual data (total_upvotes, upvote_ratio) at a certain point in time (retrieval_time).

My initial reflex is to do a query for all the reddit_ids, then iterate over that list and run a query for each id like below:

`SELECT reddit_id FROM nstats;`

Then iterate over the query results and run this query for each one:

`SELECT * FROM nstats WHERE reddit_id='9hdajv' ORDER BY retrieval_time DESC;`

This method tends to run pretty slow though, at least in my testing. I'm using Postgres with [Peewee](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/) and Python for database access.

Do I need to restructure the way I keep my data? Am I querying the right way and I just have to deal with the slow speeds? What should a single query look like to grab the most recent data for each submission?

Adding an example output to clarify. This is what the raw table would look like: multiple reddit_ids each with their own data.

```
reddit_id | retrieval_time | total_upvotes | upvote_ratio | num_comments
9hdajv | 1537471220 | 15 | .78 | 3
9hdajv | 1537298420 | 7 | .98 | 0
9hdajv | 1537384820 | 10 | .86 | 1
7klmnq | 1534706420 | 25 | .86 | 1
7klmnq | 1534965620 | 35 | .75 | 5
3poslo | 1535311220 | 16 | .75 | 3
3poslo | 1535397620 | 20 | .83 | 6
3poslo | 1535570420 | 37 | .85 | 9
```

This would be the output, 1 reddit_id each with its most current data.

```
reddit_id | retrieval_time | total_upvotes | upvote_ratio | num_comments
9hdajv | 1537471220 | 15 | .78 | 3
7klmnq | 1534965620 | 35 | .75 | 5
3poslo | 1535570420 | 37 | .85 | 9
```

Comment: Not sure why you would need to fetch the id's first? Without a data example and expected output i don't get a good feeling how the data looks like!  Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask section "Help others reproduce the problem"

Comment: Raymond, I added example data. Let me know if it needs more clarification!

Comment: What if `reddit_id  = 9hdajv` has multiple records with the same `retrieval_time = 1537471220` do they need to be also displayed?

Comment: No, just choose one of them if that slips through. That shouldn't happen in my collection code, and if it does, it doesn't matter to me which one is selected.

Comment: ok clear ive posted a answer what handles with ties correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query comes close to the expected output.

**Query**

```
SELECT 
   Table1."reddit_id"
 , Table1."retrieval_time"
 , Table1."total_upvotes"
 , Table1."upvote_ratio"
 , Table1."num_comments" 
FROM (

  SELECT 
     Table1."reddit_id"
   , Table1."retrieval_time"
   , Table1."total_upvotes"
   , Table1."upvote_ratio"
   , Table1."num_comments" 
   , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY  Table1."reddit_id" ORDER BY Table1."retrieval_time" DESC) AS row_num
  FROM 
   Table1

) AS Table1
WHERE
 Table1.row_num = 1
```

If you add

`ORDER BY 
  Table1.num_comments ASC`

the output would be the same. if you care about the order.

**Result**

```
| reddit_id | retrieval_time | total_upvotes | upvote_ratio | num_comments |
| --------- | -------------- | ------------- | ------------ | ------------ |
| 3poslo    | 1535570420     | 37            | 0.85         | 9            |
| 7klmnq    | 1534965620     | 35            | 0.75         | 5            |
| 9hdajv    | 1537471220     | 15            | 0.78         | 3            |
```

[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mdsr9HpwtQWK3nY5n4F3LA/6)

> What if reddit_id = 9hdajv has multiple records with the same
>   retrieval_time = 1537471220 do they need to be also displayed? – Raymond Nijland
>
> No, just choose one of them if that slips through. That shouldn't
>   happen in my collection code, and if it does, it doesn't matter to me
>   which one is selected  – jarcobi889

It also handle ties like requested.

[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mdsr9HpwtQWK3nY5n4F3LA/10)

Comment: That did it! Just ran it on the DB and it only took 4 minutes so it's perfect for what I need. Thanks! I need to practice more with SQL clearly

Comment: "Just ran it on the DB and it only took 4 minutes so it's perfect for what I need. Thanks!" @jarcobi889 let me check if i can get a better performing query..

Comment: No need to go too far into it if you don't have the time: the time I allocated for this query is 10 minutes and this is far below that!

Comment: I set up my timing wrong, it actually only takes 1m16s. Thanks again!

Comment: Try a index @jarcobi889 CREATE INDEX reddit_id__retrieval_time ON your_table (reddit_id, retrieval_time DESC)